# Grails deploy error

Tags: deployment, tomcat, grails

Grails grails-1.0.4 , TomCat 6.0.14 ,  Tomcat error log:

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1358)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1204)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3773)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4337)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:825)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:490)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1138)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:311)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:516)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:566)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:288)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:413)
Mar 9, 2009 3:53:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoader.java:1817)
...
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your WEB-INF/lib directory, seems as if some jars are missing.

Check your Config.groovy and make sure you aren't specifying dependencies explicitly:

```
grails.war.dependencies
grails.war.java5.dependencies
```

Comment: yes, grails.war.dependencies
grails.war.java5.dependencies resolve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I have this same problem but don't have any mention of the above two entries in my Config.groovy - is there anything else I can check?

Answer (score 0):

Please Google "grails tomcat logging".

There is some strange behavior with Tomcat and logging, which my feeble mind has forgotten, except there may be issues with log4j jars located in Tomcat's library that are duplicated in the Grails war file, or something similar, or something completely different.

But you should be able to find an answer via Google in 5-10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by overriding the templates

Answer (score 0):

this may be cause by using an older grails application to run on a latest version installed sts or any IDE ...